# asp net login with scrapy

Tags: python, asp.net, scrapy

I'm trying to perfom a login using scrapy FormRequest for this particular website 
https://www.ventureradar.com/

```
<form method="post" action="./" onsubmit="javascript:return WebForm_OnSubmit();" id="i_d_LoginButtons" class="navbar-form navbar-right col-md-3" role="search">
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="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">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['i_d_LoginButtons'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.i_d_LoginButtons;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
//]]>
</script>


<script src="/WebResource.axd?d=Kcz-Ew6evJhFZ-dJU3qdR3jBFefH_AHMnATUn3oIl7EdPiEdy0jrUhbRttuv0TbX_SxAYg49ez_iX9zo86QCQr_8QDfMTY78bAmPSfqcrgA1&amp;t=636125696399126630" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script src="/WebResource.axd?d=cgsadF9ZCRBBHsYBNAIK77TCMaXztKWYzNf21djJ9RRxfPVsnWJ7eQSxsgCczLW455eH8XEOZSrJBJpap84Qu_S-wNa9E5Ggmz-3QlizhE81&amp;t=636125696399126630" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
function WebForm_OnSubmit() {
if (typeof(ValidatorOnSubmit) == "function" && ValidatorOnSubmit() == false) return false;
return true;
}
//]]>
</script>

<div class="aspNetHidden">

    <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" value="318D363F">
</div>

                    <input name="i_h_UserID" type="hidden" id="i_h_UserID">
                    <input name="i_h_SearchKeyword" type="hidden" id="i_h_SearchKeyword">
                    <div style="" id="i_d_loginregistercontainerparent">
                        <button id="i_b_Login" type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="toggleLogin();">login</button>
                        <button id="i_b_Register" type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="toggleRegister();">free sign-up</button>



                    </div>
                    <div id="i_d_logincontainer">

                        <div id="i_d_login" style="display: none;">

                            <p>

                            </p>


                                <div style="margin-bottom: 10px">
                                    <div id="i_d_Login_Message"></div>

                                    <div>
                                        <input name="UserName" type="text" id="UserName" placeholder="Email address">
                                        <div class="formErrorsContainer">
                                            <span id="RequiredValidatorEmail" style="display:none;">Please enter Email</span><span id="RegExValidatorEmail" style="display:none;">Incorrect Email format</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div style="margin-bottom: 10px">

                                    <div>
                                        <input name="Password" type="password" id="Password" placeholder="Password">
                                        <div class="formErrorsContainer">
                                            <span id="RequiredValidatorPassword" style="display:none;">Please enter Password</span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="help-block text-right"><a href="/account/forgotpassword.aspx">Forgotten your password?</a></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div style="margin-bottom: 10px">
                                    <div>
                                        <input type="submit" name="ctl00" value="Login" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;Login&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" class="btn btn-default btn-block">
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                                <div>
```

spider code :

```
import scrapy
import json


class VentureRadar(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'vr'
    start_urls = ['https://www.ventureradar.com/']

    def parse(self, response):
        return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(response=response,
                                               clickdata=self.after_login,
                                               formdata={'UserName': 'meinherz75@gmail.com', 'Password': 'batna005'})

    def after_login(self, response):
        self.logger.info("you are at %s" % response.url)
```

the problem is that i'm getting **AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'get'** i tried also to locate the form using XPATH but no success

Comment: So you are trying to steal the data that the organisation has spent lots of time, money, and expertise to generate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a mistake in the code so i didn't specify the click data and callback here is the solution

```
def parse(self, response):
    return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(response=response,
                                            formdata={'UserName': 'email', 'Password': 'passwd'},
                                            clickdata={'id': 'i_b_Login'},
                                            callback=self.after_login)
```